# append() function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to enable the user to double-click on li elements on my webpage which then results in the addition of the li's text to a textarea below.

The user can double-click more than one li item. Every time that happens, the new item is appended to the back of the list in textarea.

I have some default text in textarea: "Double click on movie name in accordion to insert."

Hence, the following HTML code:

```
<!-- there is a list before this which I have not included -->

<div id="chosen">

<form action="process.php?stage=4" method="post">

<textarea name="g" row="5">Double click on movie name in list above to insert.</textarea>

<input type="submit" />


</form>

</div>
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
$('li').bind('dblclick', function(){ //#accordion 

    var text = $(this).html() + "; ";
    $("textarea").append(text);

    });

});
```

The code absolutely works under normal circumtances, but stops working when I click in the textarea to modify its contents. Why is this so? Is there a way to get the code to work even when I have touched the textarea's contents?

(2)
On another note, why doesn't the following code work? I tried this before I discovered the append() method. Has it got to do with $(this) scope?

```
$(document).ready (function(){
$('li').bind('dblclick', function(){ //#accordion 

    var text = $(this).html() + "; ";
    $("textarea").html( function() { //.chosen 

       var currenthtml = $(this).html(); // retrieve the current HTML first 
       currenthtml += text;
        return currenthtml;      });

    });

});
```

(3) Also, how do I program functionality that allows, if the user has already double-clicked a li element to include it into textarea, to undo that inclusion? Is there a method that allows me  to do the opposite of append()?

Comment: only ask one question pr post

Answer (score 2):

Just an answer for your question 2)

The html() function is used to get or to insert text into HTML tags (example: `<div></div>`); the content of the textarea is not html. The equivalent is:

```
  $("textarea").val("Hello World!");
```

For your first question, i've made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhKwQ/ , <s>and it works perfectly (tested in Chrome 26), even if i click into the textarea. Can you try to reproduce your behavior into the fiddle?</s>

Ok you're right when editing, it doesn't work anymore...

**EDIT:**: It works with the val() function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').bind('dblclick', function () { //#accordion 

        var text = $(this).html() + "; ";
        $("textarea").val($("textarea").val() + text);

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhKwQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

As answer for question #1:

Try setting the value in the following way instead of the append method.

```
$("[name=g]").val(text);
```

For some reason, it seems that it loses it focus on the textarea element.

With using [name=g] it will look for and element with that specific name and assign a value.

you could also use the following to be even more specific:

```
$("textarea[name=g]").val(text);
```

---

This should also solve your question #3.

Answer (score 0):

for your second question

```
var text = $(this).html()
```

in this line `this`points to the `li element but in

```
var currenthtml = $(this).html();
```

`this` is the `textarea` element and not the `li` element

for your 3rd question. You will have to manually bring the value of the textarea back to it's previous state (using `.append()`) there's no undo functionality